# Storing configuration in Tornado projects and Celery

Tags: python, celery, tornado, etcd

I am faced with the problem in the Tornado project using Celery tasks.
Right now I use `*.conf` files and `tornado.options` to parse them.
`tornado.options` parses configuration files and command line.

Also there is Celery `app` object in the projec. So when I start celery worker, it doesn't know about command line and configuration files, so I get errors.

The question is how to store configuration to ditribute it betweeen backend servers and workers? The questions is more about your experiences and best practices.

I've heard about ditributed configurations systems such as `etcd`. Is it useful for Tornado/Celery projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.config_from_object(x)` to configure your Celery app from an existing object. You can then set up your app's file something like this:

```
app = Celery("myappname")
tornado_config = get_tornado_config()
celery_config = tornado_config.celery
app.config_from_object(celery_config)
```

E.g. Store your celery settings inside your tornado configuration and access it from there. Then you don't need to distinguish between backend servers and workers, at least not in terms of package installation.

Comment: Excuse me, what should return `get_tornado_config` exactly?

Comment: Anyway thank you. Just the part of the problem that tornado configs can't be read when workers are run. We just dont call `tornado.options.parse_config_file`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do that in your celery app file?